# Illustrator knows I have a font but refuses to select it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I need to use a specific font (Nanum Gothic Extra Bold) for a certain project. Illustrator knows I have the font: If I start typing the name in, it autocompletes. But once I hit return, it selects a different font. And the font doesn't appear on the list.

What's going wrong and how can I get access to this font?

Comment: have you verified the font is in good working order? Using any font management tools?

Comment: Just Mac's built-in Font Book. That seems t be able to pick up the one font fine. Any other tests of font integrity you'd recommend I run?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is years old now but I thought I'd provide an insight. I work on a PC and needed to use that font (nanungothic) within Illustrator CS5 as well.  Would show up when I typed it into the window but not convert the font.

I opened up the preferences and under the `Type` tab, ticked `Show asian options` and `Show font names in English`.

Showed up after that in regular, bold, and extra bold. Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem for months now. Every other solution involved clearing the font cache but yielded no results. This suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try rebuilding or clearing your font caches. Corrupted font caches can cause many problems. [Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf5ZuiaYgus) on how to do that on a Mac.

Perhaps then try to reset your Illustrator prefs, by manually deleting them or adjusting them: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-630ca.html

Maybe that will help - also if you own the font, contact that font foundry to see if there are any other reports of this issue.

Comment: Not really. That link talks about using a separate tool I don't have to clear the font cache. It did point me to Adobe's own Troubleshooting Fonts page, but the instructions there for clearing the cache were behind the times: In my version of OS X, the commands they recommend for 10.5 and all after aren't supported any more.

Comment: I did eventually clear all font caches using the freeware tool "FontNuke". Unfortunately, this wasn't the problem.